# How to store value in separate array or variable in cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

There is H4 tag which contains 5 different values. I want to store it in one variable & get one by one value of h4.
**Here i attach image which shows h4 length 5.**
[image]

**Here is the code**

```
cy.get('.box-product').get('h4').invoke('text').then((text2)=> {
            cy.log(text2)
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `then()` along with `Array.from` to save all the `h4` elements in a array.

```
cy.get('h4').then(($ele) => {
    const texts = Array.from($ele, el => el.innerText);
    texts.forEach(text => cy.log(text));
})
```

Or, if you want to access each value of the `h4` you can also use `each()`

```
cy.get('h4').then(($ele) => {
    const text = $ele.text()
    cy.log(text)
})
```

Comment: How to print its value using loop?

Comment: You can use the `each()` method to print the value one by one.

Comment: No, not like that.
If i write in this
cy.get('h4').then(($ele) => {
    const texts = Array.from($ele, el => el.innerText);
    cy.log(texts)
})

cy.log(texts[0]) -> It eill give me the text of 1st element.
What if i want to print cy.log(texts[0]), cy.log(texts[1]), cy.log(texts[3]) all value upto produced length ?